# Using citations with Workbench

Tags: workbench

I have written a tutorial (.nb file) for a package using Workbench. In the tutorial there are some citations created with the recently introduced citation management system. They are simply numbered links to footnoted text. Nothing fancy. It works well initially: I click on the link and the .nb file scrolls to the corresponding footnote.

However, after I create a build, the links no longer work in the built tutorial file.

The n-th link target appears to be :paclet/ref/n and it does not work anymore.

Can someone please confirm this (possible) bug and/or suggest workarounds?